# Linux to Linux GUI Remote

Tags: linux, remote-access

I wants to access **GUI** of Linux machine from another Linux machine.

I can access its terminal using "**ssh username@IP_Address**" command but i wants the access of its GUI.

Comment: @Downvoters: Please give RAVI a feedback why you down-vote his question so he can do it better next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use SSH tunneling and VNC. You will need to set up a VNC server on your remote machine and start a vnc session.

Add the `-L` flag on your SSH connect. `-L 5555:localhost:5901` - this means bind local port 5555 to 5901 on the remote machine.

Finally, use `vncviewer localhost:5555` to connect to the remote machine through SSH.

Doing it this way, all your traffic will be sent over SSH and be encrypted. This is important, because VNC is an unencrypted protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "-X" flag:

```
$ ssh -X user@server.corp.com
```

Comment: With help of **-X** i can run its applications but when my Linux machine will be disconnected from that machine, the process will be terminated. I don't want to terminate the process when my Linux machine shutdown. (Using rdesktop i can access windows machines and i can run its applications. In rdesktop if my machine disconnects from that machine the process will not be terminated.)